# Is it possible to override just one column type when using PySpark to read in a CSV?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to use PySpark to read in a CSV file with many columns.  The `inferschema` option is great at inferring majority of the columns' data types.  If I want to override just one of the columns types that were inferred incorrectly, what is the best way to do this?

I have this code working, but it makes PySpark import only the one column that is specified in the schema, which is not want I want.

```
schema = StructType() \ 
    .add("column_one_of_many", StringType(), True) 

spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv') \ 
  .option('delimited',',') \ 
  .option('header','true') \ 
  .option('inferschema', 'true') \ 
  .schema(self.schema) \ 
  .load('dbfs:/FileStore/some.csv')
```

Is what I'm asking for even possible?

Thank you for your time and guidance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easier way would be using `.withColumn` and casting `column_one_of_many`  as string.

**`Example`**

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv') \ 
  .option('delimited',',') \ 
  .option('header','true') \ 
  .option('inferschema', 'true') \ 
  .load('dbfs:/FileStore/some.csv')\
  .withColumn("column_one_of_many",col("column_one_of_many").cast("string"))
```

---

Other way would be defining all the columns in schema then exclude the `inferschema` just use **`.schema`** option to read the csv file.

Comment: that's perfect, thank you!  `.withColumn` was exactly what I was trying to find.  I did not want to define everything in the schema.  Thanks again  

Answer (score 2):

Or you could read it in first with `inferSchema` turned on, modify the schema, then load in the csv again:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

df = spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv') \ 
  .option('delimited',',') \ 
  .option('header','true') \ 
  .option('inferschema', 'true') \ 
  .load('dbfs:/FileStore/some.csv')
```

For example, let's change the first column (indexed by `0`) from `IntegerType` to `StringType`:

```
df.schema.fields[0].dataType = StringType
schema = df.schema
```

Then, reload the csv with the modified schema:

```
df = spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv') \ 
  .option('delimited',',') \ 
  .option('header','true') \ 
  .option('schema', schema) \ 
  .load('dbfs:/FileStore/some.csv')
```

Of course, you can modify any of the columns' data type this way by selecting the correct index. This method is better than casting in cases where you might lose info by the original type inference (e.g. zip codes that start with a zero).